# Extjs Form submit not sending binary data of file during upload

Tags: extjs, file-upload, extjs5

I am trying to do a file upload using Extjs 5. But I don't see the binary data of file in the Request Payload. I can only see the textfield data and cannot see the data of file I am trying to upload.

Sencha fiddler link for your reference: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/beh

Attached is the screenshot of request headers.
[image]

I will appreciate any help provided, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set some name of filefield:

```
xtype: 'filefield',
name: 'file',
anchor: '100%',
fieldLabel: 'Label'
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot now, but that solved my problem perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

khmurach's answer is correct.  But to clarify and also make it easier for others to find this answer I'll add the following.

From the ExtJS API for Ext.form.field.File:

name - The name of the field. This is used as the parameter name when including the field value in a form submit(). If no name is configured, it falls back to the inputId. To prevent the field from being included in the form submit, set submitValue to false.

To put this another way.  You **MUST either specify a "name" (or "inputId") in the filefield configuration or otherwise set "submitValue" to false** else the submission will be sent as an incomplete multipart POST which will cause errors such as:

- Exception EOFError in Rack application object (bad content body)
- Premature end of script headers: